# How can I add a column in an existing table?

Tags: powershell

For example I use `Get-Service`. There are 3 columns namely "status", "name", "displayname", if I want to add a 4th column name `Label`, how can I do it? I would like to mark each status that is equal to running with yes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [calculated Property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx):

```
Get-Service | 
    Select Status, Name, DisplayName, @{Name='Label'; Expression={if ($_.Status -eq 'Running') {'Yes'} else {'No'} } }
```

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful :)